# $ \|T_n\| \not \rightarrow \|T\|$ even if $ T_nx \rightarrow Tx, \forall x $

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

There is a theorem which states that given $X$ normed space, $Y$ Banach space on $\mathbb R, D \subseteq X$ dense and $T_n \in \mathcal L(X,Y)$ a bounded sequence s.t. $T_nz$ converges $\forall z \in D$ then $\exists T \in \mathcal L(X,Y)$ s.t. $T_n x \rightarrow Tx, \forall x \in X.$

Is it possible to have $\|T_n\|_{\mathcal L} \not \rightarrow \|T\|_{\mathcal L}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a Hilbert space with basis $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$. Let $T_n$ be the orthogonal projection onto the Hilbert space generated by $\{e_i\}_{i=n}^\infty$.

Comment: Indeed. It is useful, however, to note that at least, $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\|T_n\|\ge\|T\|$.

Comment: Ok, may be a bit thick but in this example $\lim\|T_n\|=1$ and $\|T\|=0$?